# Keil MDK to run ARM assembly with unexpected results

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I am trying to run my first assembly on Keil MDK.
The link I learn is below:

[ARM Assembly Language Tutorial - Part 1 - Setup ARM Tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sm6v9UyhCkA)

The first thing I have done is to write my assembly and configure all things for the IDE settings.

[image]

Second, since I dont have the real device in hand so I need to debug this in the simulator.

[image]

Third, when I enter the debug mode, and press the  "step over" button,

It did not work as what I expected to have. R0 did not change its value and there is no green bar appeared while it is in the tutorial video.

[image]

Is there anything I've done wrong?

My first time using this IDE so please correct me if I might miss any thing.

=====================================================================

updated screenshot:

[image]

Comment: (rant: entirely not your fault, but I have no desire to spend 11 minutes patiently watching a video of something which, if it were written down and illustrated with screenshots, I could skim for the important details in seconds...) Anyway, those error and warning messages seem to describe exactly what's going on: you appear to be simulating a Cortex-M device, but have no [vector table](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABIFJFG.html) defined, so it looks to be interpreting the instruction at 0x0 as a nonsense stack pointer address and falling over.

Comment: ...what I don't know is whether the code is wrong and you need to define some vectors, or you're actually trying to simulate the "classic" (ARM7/ARM9/etc.) architecture, in which case you'd need to change the simulator settings and compile the code as ARM, not Thumb. It would help to have all the important details in the question itself.

Comment: @Notlikethat,
This is my first time to use this IDE to do the test. Your assumption is correct that I am trying to simulate the Coretex-M device and I was thinking the vector table should be defined when I chose the target device by default.
The warning message is ".\Objects\arm2.axf: Warning: L6320W: Ignoring --first command. Cannot find argument '__Vectors'."

Comment: In this case, how can I add the definition of vector table? please help, thanks.

Comment: btw, currently I dont find any device in ARM7/ARM9 architecture available in the packet installer, is there any device I could install to simulate ARM7/ARM9 ?

Comment: @Notlikethat, any advice please ?

Comment: I dunno, I've never touched MDK ;) With a GCC-based toolchain you'd typically have the linker script generate the vector table in the final image. With armcc, I don't know if the map file handles that, or whether it's purely for section layout and vectors happen some other way.